# How to generate n points and restrict the distance between them to be greater than a given value?

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to generate, randomly with uniform distribution, n points such that the distance between any point is greater than some fixed value.

Here is the scenario that I have in MATLAB:

- I have M red points which I generate randomly with uniform distribution as follow: the x-abscissa of the M red points are `xr = rand(1, M)` and the y-ordinate of the M red points are `yr = rand(1, M)`.
- Also, I have M black points which I generate similarly as the red points, i.e., `xb = rand(1, M)` and `yb = rand(1, M)`.
- Then, I calculate the distances between all the points as follow:

  ```
  x = [xr, xb];
  y = [yr, yb];
  D = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus, x, x').^2 + bsxfun(@minus, y, y').^2);
  d = D(1:M, M + 1:end);
  ```
- Now, **I have to restrict the distance `d` to be always greater than some given value, say `d0=0.5`**.

How to do this?

Comment: To get a truly uniform distribution conditioned on a minimun distance, I can only think of a pure rejection method (generate the points, check the condition, and if it's not satisfied repeat). But that will be costly

Comment: Question shall be reformulated as generating random non-cverlapping circles with given radius. Good discussion here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69649/generate-nonoverlapping-random-circles

Comment: Without the distance/length constraint, this problem is sometimes referred to as [square line picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html). I like the mapping of this to random disks/circles.

Comment: Can you generate all of the points in the uniform distribution, and then scale them, such that the scale factor is computed to be your minimum fixed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While such sampling (which is equivalent to non-overlapping circles generation) is discussed on math.stackexchange, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69649/generate-nonoverlapping-random-circles, I would like to point out to another potential solution which involves quasi-random numbers. For quasi-random Sobol sequences there is a statement which says that there is minimum positive distance between points which amounts to `0.5*sqrt(d)/N`, where `d` is dimension of the problem, and `N` is number of points sampled in hypercube. Paper from the man himself http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382